How to I run a function over all markup code / change the way it is displayed?
I am viewing some text in a buffer with the markdown filetype. I'd like this text to be rendered differently (specifically, I want to remove ^A control characters from the window) without modifying the file (ie. I just want this to be a visual change).
How can I make arbitrary changes to the way characters or text is displayed in a markup buffer in neovim?

Could you please [edit] and show an example?

I have assumed markdown instead of markup. I see no reference to the markup filetype in the documentation or in the code of Neovim.

@VivianDeSmedt yes that's right, apologies.

Do you still have something open in your question? How could we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

I would do:
:call matchadd('Conceal', '^A')
:set conceallevel=2


call matchadd('Conceal', '^A') make the pattern ^A associated to the Conceal highlighting group,
set conceallevel=2 makes the concealable section hidden when the cursor is not on the line of the section.

To apply these changes for all files of the markdown filetype you could add a ~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim file with the following content:
call matchadd('Conceal', '^A')
setlocal conceallevel=2

Remark: the ~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim is executed after:

The buffer filetype is set to markdown.
The other plugins ftplugin/markdown.vim are executed


How can I make this automatically be applied for all markdown filetypes?
